# Could not start Selenium session: You may not start more than one session at a time

Tags: selenium-webdriver

this is a configuration error , when trying to configure selenium with eclipse , what i read in a couple of websites is that , adding a dependency to maven would do , but nothing worked  , i have been spending a lot of hours/day , even modified the system property , to add firefox profile into it , but nothing worked . looks like i am the first one on this earth to get this error

thankyou

pasting a stack trace , for your reference 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start Selenium session: You may not start more than one session at a time
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:90)
    at TestAddVisitor.setUp(TestAddVisitor.java:36)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase.runBare(SeleneseTestCase.java:228)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:110)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:128)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:113)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:232)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:227)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: You may not start more than one session at a time
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.start(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:217)
    at org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverCommandProcessor.start(WebDriverCommandProcessor.java:208)
    at com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium.start(DefaultSelenium.java:82)
    ... 16 more

Answer (score 9):

I guess this is not a configuration error. If my understanding is correct you are are creating `WebDriver` object and then creating `DefaultSelenium` / `Selenium` object with it and then starting the selenium session.

then -- don't use `DefaultSelenium.start()` method.

Code should be like this:

```java
DefaultSelenium ds = new DefaultSelenium(
        new WebDriverCommandProcessor("baseURL",new FirefoxDriver()));
// ds.start(); -- do not do this
ds.open("/");
```

This might help you.

Comment: Thankyou it did help :) I realised the problem was that 2 sessions were getting created

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#webdriver-backed-selenium-rc? [sudarsan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799129/sudarsan) in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6385181/could-not-start-selenium-session-you-may-not-start-more-than-one-session-at-a-ti/6400525#6400525)  is right: don't do `selenium.start`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wonder that the JUnit Code from the Selenium IDE throughs this exception, see http://osdir.com/ml/selenium-users/2011-07/msg02107.html